# jQuery can't get radiobutton correct checked value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like the title says I can't get the checked value of a radio button, even though in the debugger I can see it, and it's checked

[image: screenshot]

I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I have no idea what it is. Any help?

Thanks!

Code:

```
function setupViewAll() {
        var comparisonCount = 0;
        var maxComparisonCount = 3;
        var $compareLabels = $('.compare-label');
        $compareLabels.addClass('compare-label-visible');

        // Check if the checkboxes are checked on load (in case the user navigates back), and if they are increase the check count.
        $compareLabels.each(function(index, label) {
            var radioButton = $(label).find('.radio-input');
            // Only show tooltip on unchecked checkboxes.
            if(radioButton.checked) {
                comparisonCount++;
                console.log(comparisonCount);
                checkSetToolTip($compareLabels, comparisonCount, maxComparisonCount);
            }
        });

        $('.infinit-view-all').click(function (e) {
            console.log("click in view all.");
            var $parent = $(e.target).parent();

            if ($parent.hasClass('compare-label')) {
                var radioButton = $parent.find('radio-input'); // this was the error, I needed '.radio-input', instead of 'radio-input'.
                console.log(radioButton);
                if (radioButton !== undefined) {
                    // If comparisonCount > maxComparisonCount, prevent click from bubbling up.
                    alert(radioButton.is(":checked"));
                    if (comparisonCount == maxComparisonCount) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you please post your source code in JSFiddle?

Comment: No point, it won't work. There are more dependencies on it. I just want to know how to find the checked value of a checkbox.

Comment: What console errors are you getting?

Comment: How about using `radioButton[0].checked;`, which is 130 times [faster](https://jsperf.com/prop-vs-ischecked/5)

Comment: @JCOC611 checked returns as undefined, for some reason.

Comment: @Hanoncs no console errors, the console is visible in the screenshot on my question, that's all it is.

Comment: @JCOC611 Based on the radioButton variable on the screenshot, the element really has a "checked" property set to true, right? If yes, why wouldn't I be able to get it with the console commands I used? (also in the screenshot).

Comment: It might be worth it to note that the `checked` property you mention is **not** `radioButton.checked`, but `radioButton.context.checked`, and that such *context* doesn't refer to the element you selected. You might be using the wrong selector.

Comment: @JCOC611 that's what I was thinking...

Comment: Like what selector are you using and what's your HTML...

Answer (score 0):

This is basic code. It shouldn't be hard to combine with your code.

```
$('#element').click(function() {
   if($('#radio_button').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }
});
```

**TRY THIS**

```
function setupViewAll() {
        var comparisonCount = 0;
        var maxComparisonCount = 3;
        var $compareLabels = $('.compare-label');
        $compareLabels.addClass('compare-label-visible');

        // Check if the checkboxes are checked on load (in case the user navigates back), and if they are increase the check count.
        $compareLabels.each(function(index, label) {
            var radioButton = $(label).find('.radio-input');
            // Only show tooltip on unchecked checkboxes.
            if(radioButton.checked) {
                comparisonCount++;
                console.log(comparisonCount);
                checkSetToolTip($compareLabels, comparisonCount, maxComparisonCount);
            }
        });

        $('.infinit-view-all').click(function (e) {
            console.log("click in view all.");
            var $parent = $(e.target).parent();

            if ($parent.hasClass('.compare-label')) {
                var radioButton = $parent.find('.radio-input');
                console.log(radioButton);
                if (radioButton !== undefined) {
                    // If comparisonCount > maxComparisonCount, prevent click from bubbling up.
                      if($parent.find('.radio-input').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }
                    if (comparisonCount == maxComparisonCount) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the value, you have to select all of the potential radio buttons with the same name and filter it to what has been checked, i.e. using `:checked`. You can then use `.val()` to get the value of that specific radio button.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#check').click(function() {
        alert($('input[name="the-super-radio"]:checked').val());
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="the-super-radio" value="1" />
<input type="radio" name="the-super-radio" value="2" />
<input type="radio" name="the-super-radio" value="3" />

<button id="check">Check</button>
```

In production you should probably further refine your selector to ensure just incase multiple forms on the page have elements with the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, .val() also returns as undefined =/

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I ran this $().jquery and got 1.11.1